# What's the meaning of linear coordinate representation?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image: Lee83]

What's the meaning of linear coordinate representation?

Comment: That for some charts $\phi:U\subset M\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\psi:V\subset N\to\mathbb{R}^n$ on neighborhoods $U$ of $p$ and $V$ of $f(p)$, the function $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is linear. A coordinate representation of $f$ is a $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$. It is how $f$ looks for some choice of coordinates $\phi$ and $\psi$ in its domain and co-domain.

Comment: Also, check formula (4.1), which should be an example.

Comment: @user647486 What's the meaning of that $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is linear?

Comment: @user647486 You mean the image of $\phi$ is $\Bbb R^m$, don't you?

Comment: Linear means [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), or if you want being equal to a multiplication by a matrix, in the case of maps $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$. In general $m\neq n$, since the manifolds don't have to be of the same dimension.